# Rabbitmq unable to find erl after Mac OS update

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, homebrew, erl

After updating high sierra to 10.13.5, rabbitmq can't seem to find erl when i run:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq/3.7.3/sbin/rabbitmq-server
```

I get the error:

> /usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq/3.7.3/sbin/rabbitmq-server: line 85:
>   /usr/local/opt/erlang/bin/erl: No such file or directory

Running `which erl` gives me: `/usr/local/bin/erl`

Need help to get it working again, not sure why the path changed as well.

Comment: For me it's working well try to `brew upgrade`.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni this did not work for me. Upgraded brew same error

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to install [erlang](https://www.erlang.org/) with

```
brew install erlang
```

or reinstall it with:

```
brew reinstall erlang
```